# "resourcesUrl" in cumulocity.json not working?

Tags: cumulocity

I have cloned the sample myapplication from here(https://cumulocity.com/guides/web/introduction/) and it works.

However, when I change the resourcesUrl to point to my bitbucket repos, it starts getting funny.

`{
  "availability": "MARKET",
  "contextPath": "myapplication",
  "key": "myapplication-appkey",
  "name": "myapplication",
  "resourcesUrl": "https://bitbucket.org/m2m/cumulocity-ui-plugin-examples/raw/develop/build",
  "type": "HOSTED",
  "imports": [
    "core/c8yBranding",
    "core/deviceList",
    "core/deviceDetail",
    "myapplication/myplugin"
  ]
}`

Each time I switch to myapplication on cumulocity, my page will automatically forwarded to bitbucket. Even I delete the myapplication from administration and change back "resourcesUrl" to original, and reregister plugin and app, the portal still continues to forward the page to bitbucket.

Did I miss anything here and how to bring back? Thanks.

---

Updates,

1. Looks reregistering the app with original resourcesUrl does work today and possibly was something not right with my PC yesterday.(today I found this is not related to my PC, their is a delay between grunt appRegister and the application is really updated in Cumulocity, wonder how long the delay is?)
2. The myapplication is forwarded to bitbucket looks to be related to if the repo is private or public. If the repo is public, cumulocity will load the login page as expected. If private, even in the Administration page->Own applications->Myapplication->properties page, set username and password and click save, still goes to bitbucket login page. 
   So now the question is, how to link("resourcesUrl") to a private repo hosted in bitbucket?
3. If change "availability" from "MARKET" to "PRIVATE", the application page will be 404 no application found, is this expected?
   Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To point to a `resourcesUrl` that is protected by basic authentication, which is the case for private bitbucket repos, one must add the properties `resourcesUsername` and `resourcesPassword` to the manifest.
In case of bitbucket these are the credentials to a bitbucket user. We recommend a user with just read permissions to this repo.

A `MARKET`is available to every tenant that subscribes it and a `PRIVATE`app is only available to the tenant that owns it. For example, if a tenant 'acme' creates an application 'foo' that same app will only be available at acme.cumulocity.com/apps/foo.